# PyQt and QML: How can multiple signals be processed in one slot or function

Tags: python, qml, pyqt5

I have now spent quite a while to figure out how to connect QML signals to slots in python and also how to communicate with the QML GUI again. But I cannot figure out how to send multiple GUI inputs to the same slot/function in python.

Here is a basic example of what is supposed to happen:
The user manipulates the SpinBoxes in the GUI and the sum of them is displayed in the GUI again.
I assume this is either done by routing several signals into one slot or by routing each signal into an individual slot and letting python do the combining somehow. But apparently the pyqt slots don't allow for "return" either.

Help is much appreciated!

QML:
(The commented lines are what I thought might work but it does not. It results in "Expected token `identifier'" when the signal line is not commented.)

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow{
    visible:true
    width:200
    height:300
    id:window
    title: "Signal/Slot Test"

    Rectangle{

        //signal somethingChanged(int, int)

        //function exportSignals() {
        //    somethingChanged(spin1.value, spin2.value)
        //}

        Column {
            spacing: 20
            width: parent.width


            SpinBox {
                id: spin1
                signal sig_spin1(int spin1_int)
                objectName: "spin1"
                value: 50
                width: 120
                editable: true
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    console.log("Spin1: " + spin1.value)
                    sig_spin1(spin1.value)
                    //exportSignals()
                }
                onValueChanged: {
                    console.log("Spin1: " + spin1.value)
                    sig_spin1(spin1.value)
                    //exportSignals()
                }
            }

            SpinBox {
                id: spin2
                signal sig_spin2(int spin2_int)
                objectName: "spin2"
                value: 50
                width: 120
                editable: true
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    console.log("Spin2: " + spin2.value)
                    sig_spin2(spin2.value)
                    //exportSignals()
                }
                onValueChanged: {
                    console.log("Spin2: " + spin2.value)
                    sig_spin2(spin2.value)
                    //exportSignals()
                }
            }

            Label {
                id: label_spin1
                objectName: "label_spin1"
                text: "Start Value"
            }

            Label {
                id: label_spin2
                objectName: "label_spin2"
                text: "Start Value"
            }

            Label {
                id: label_result
                objectName: "label_result"
                text: "Sum"
            }

        }
    }
}
```

and the python code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QUrl, Qt, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine


def spin1_update(spin1_int):
    print("Spin 1 updated")
    label_spin1 = win.findChild(QObject, "label_spin1")
    label_spin1.setProperty("text", spin1_int)

def spin2_update(spin2_int):
    print("Spin 2 updated")
    label_spin2 = win.findChild(QObject, "label_spin2")
    label_spin2.setProperty("text", spin2_int)


def spin_sum(spin1_int, spin2_int):
    my_sum = spin1_int + spin2_int
    label_result = win.findChild(QObject, "label_result")
    label_result.setProperty("text", my_sum)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.load('main.qml')
    win = engine.rootObjects()[0]

    spin1 = win.findChild(QObject, "spin1")
    spin1.sig_spin1.connect(spin1_update)

    spin2 = win.findChild(QObject, "spin2")
    spin2.sig_spin2.connect(spin2_update)

    #win.exportSignals.connect()


    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**UPDATE. For completeness, a working example:**
main.py:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, pyqtProperty,     QCoreApplication, QObject, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtQml import QQmlEngine, QQmlApplicationEngine
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication



class GuiInteraction(QObject):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)


    @pyqtSlot(int, int, result=int)
    def get_sum(self, spin1, spin2):
        print("Spin1 from python: ", spin1)
        print("Spin2 from the same python slot: ", spin2)
        my_sum = spin1 + spin2
        print(my_sum)
        print()
        return my_sum




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    guiInteraction = GuiInteraction()

    engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
    ctx = engine.rootContext()
    ctx.setContextProperty("guiInteraction", guiInteraction)
    engine.load('main.qml')
    win = engine.rootObjects()[0]


    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0

ApplicationWindow{
    visible:true
    width:200
    height:300
    id:window
    title: "Signal/Slot Test"



    Rectangle{

        Column {
            spacing: 20
            width: parent.width


            SpinBox {
                id: spin1
                value: 50
                width: 120
                editable: true
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    console.log("Spin1: " + spin1.value)

                }
                onValueChanged: {
                    console.log("Spin1: " + spin1.value)

                    label_result.text = guiInteraction.get_sum(spin1.value, spin2.value)
                }
            }

            SpinBox {
                id: spin2
                value: 50
                width: 120
                editable: true
                Component.onCompleted: {
                    console.log("Spin2: " + spin2.value)

                }
                onValueChanged: {
                    console.log("Spin2: " + spin2.value)
                    label_result.text = guiInteraction.get_sum(spin1.value, spin2.value)
                }
            }


            Label {
                id: label_result
                objectName: "label_result"
                text: "Nothing yet."
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use Python to set the value of the labels? Just as with C++, where you can set values from C++, but you are not advised to do so, I doubt that it is a good style to do it in PyQt.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand how this is supposed to work. I don't know C++ but do know some Python. So naturally I want to perform some computation in Python from values that the user can set in the qml gui and then send them back to the gui. Is this completely out of scope of PyQt? I would think it is a very natural use case.

Comment: What I meant is what Kevin Krammer described in his answer. You should use property bindings to get the values to the QML-Side. So instead of using Python to write to the QML-Side, you use QML to read from the Python-Side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you wouldn't do any of that on Python or C++ side, especially not the updating of the value labels.

For the value labels you would simply use property bindings, e.g.:

```
Label {
    text: "Start value: " + spin1.value
}
```

For a trivial calculation like a sum you would do the same.

Now, assuming the calculation is more complex and you would want to do that on the Python side, then you would not need any signals on the QML side.

Instead, one option would be to have a `QObject` derived class in Python that provides a slot which takes both arguments.

An instance of that object would be exposed to QML via the `setContextProperty()` mechanism of the QML engine's `rootContext()`.
Each spinbox' `onValueChanged` handler can then call this slot with both values.

For the result the slot could either return the value, or the object could provide a result property that is updated by the slot and which is used in QML as a binding on the result label.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two signals connected to the same slot in the way that you suggest. All a signal does is trigger the code in the slot to run once; it's not a true continuous connection like a physical wire in electronics (which is what I imagine you might be imagining).

When one spinbox value changes, you'll need to retrieve the other spinbox value (either from the spinbox itself, from the labels, or from another variable where you've stored it) to do the addition. For example:

```
def spin1_update(spin1_int):
    print("Spin 1 updated")
    label_spin1 = win.findChild(QObject, "label_spin1")
    label_spin1.setProperty("text", spin1_int)
    spin_sum()

def spin2_update(spin2_int):
    print("Spin 2 updated")
    label_spin2 = win.findChild(QObject, "label_spin2")
    label_spin2.setProperty("text", spin2_int)
    spin_sum()

def spin_sum():
    spin1 = win.findChild(QObject, "spin1")
    spin2 = win.findChild(QObject, "spin2")
    my_sum = spin1.value() + spin2.value()

    label_result = win.findChild(QObject, "label_result")
    label_result.setProperty("text", my_sum)
```

In this case, there's no need to connect spin_sum() to anything. It's already called directly by the two preceding slot functions.

Comment: The global variables' are still "0" in the spin_sum() function, though! And the return does not work to make them available outside the update slots. So this still does not work. Or maybe I need a coffee...

Comment: OK, the global variables actually have to be set to global in the update functions, i.e.: `global spin1_global`. But out of curiosity, how would the other way work where the values from the spinboxes are directly used. I guess that is the original question.

Comment: I modified my answer, but the thing is that I can't actually test it at the moment, so there could be some minor errors.